# Como manter uma função JS após refresh?

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando implementar esta função:

```
function aumentarFont() {
document.getElementById("myP").style.fontSize = "medium";
}
```

Executa a ação:

```
<a href="#" type="text" onclick="aumentarFont()">A+</a>
```

Aparentemente esta funcionando corretamente, porém quando dou um refresh na página a font volta ao seu tamanho normal. Como eu faço para que essa função continue executada após o refresh?

Comment: Vai ter que salvar o tamanho dessa fonte em algum lugar (no servidor - banco de dados, ou no cliente - `localStorage`, etc.) e trabalhar numa maneira de "*setar*" essa configuração sempre que carregar a página.

Comment: que tal usar session